# How to exclude a method using excludebyfile in OpenCover

Tags: opencover

I'm using AxoCover, which uses OpenCover to generate reports.

The OpenCover usage for `excludebyfile` is

> `-excludebyfile:<filter>[;<filter>][;<filter>]` - Exclude a class (or methods) by filter(s) that match the filenames. An * can be used as a wildcard.

I want to exclude the `Dispose` method in my controllers without having to decorate them all with the `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` attribute, therefore I am intrigued by the **(or methods)** part of the usage.

I have tried:

- `Dispose` - still included (I didn't really think that would work, but it was worth a try)
- `*Dispose*` - still included
- `*.Dispose*` - still included
- `*Controller.Dispose*` - still included
- `*.cs*Dispose*` - still included

I tried using the syntax for `-filter` e.g. `-[*]*.Dispose*`, but the tests failed to run.

Note that AxoCover doesn't allow the editing of the `-filter` argument or I would have tried using that approach.

What is the syntax for excluding methods using the `excludebyfile` argument?

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I ended up using a couple of approaches.  Move the functions into a partial class in a separate file and exclude that file, or simply write a test that called the method.